# How to check valid url?

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, nspredicate, nsurl

How I can check NSURL is valid or not?
1) If I enter "facebook.com" then it should add "http://www."

2) If I enter "www.facebook.com",then it should add "http://"

3) If I enter "facebook", then It should search on google.

How I can achieve this??

I am doing this following way, but it is not working. It always return true for third case.("http://www.facebook")

```
if (![url.absoluteString.lowercaseString hasPrefix:@"http://"])
    {
        if(![url.absoluteString.lowercaseString hasPrefix:@"www."])
        {
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://www." stringByAppendingString:locationField.text]];

        }
        else
        {
            url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:locationField.text]];
        }
    }
if(![self validateUrl:url.absoluteString])
{
     url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",[locationField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
}


 - (BOOL) validateUrl:(NSString *)candidate
{
  NSString *urlRegEx = @"((https|http)://)((\\w|-)+)(([.]|[/])((\\w|-)+))+";
  NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
  return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

Comment: add a nslog for this url.absoluteString, and paste the result

Comment: Your logic is incorrect. For the URL `facebook` you end up changing it to `http://www.facebook` and then validation it.

Comment: @Walucas nslog = absoluteString=http://www.facebook

Comment: @rmaddy how would I know, is it facebook or facebook.com?

Comment: Check if the string ends with a valid TLD or not.

Comment: how can I check for valid TLD?

Comment: BTW - not all domains should have `www` added to them. What if the user enters `stackoverflow.com`? You want to add the `http://` but not `www`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to add `www.` if user enter `facebook.com`. The `http://` would be enough. Anyway the following function can eat either with or without `www.`

```
func checkURL(url: String ) -> Bool {    
    let urlRegEx = "^http(?:s)?://(?:w{3}\\.)?(?!w{3}\\.)(?:[\\p{L}a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.){1,}(?:[\\p{L}a-zA-Z]{2,})/(?:\\S*)?$"
    let urlTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx)
    return urlTest.evaluateWithObject(url)
}

checkURL("http://www.россия.рф/") // true
checkURL("http://www.facebook.com/") // true
checkURL("http://www.some.photography/") // true
checkURL("http://facebook.com/") // true

checkURL("http://www.россия/") // false
checkURL("http://www.facebook/") // false
checkURL("http://www.some/") // false
checkURL("http://facebook/") // false

checkURL("http://россия.рф/") // true
checkURL("http://facebook.com/") // true
checkURL("http://some.photography/") // true
checkURL("http://com/") // false
```

Comment: You are assuming 2 or 3 letter TLD at the end. What about "info" and many of the new TLDs that are more than 3 letters?

Comment: Thanks, It is working but as @rmaddy saying, for more than 3 letter, it will not work?

Comment: @Rox fixed for 4 letter TLD

Comment: Then what about .travel etc?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains for a huge list of TLDs that can be almost any word. Simply checking for 2-4 letters (or any specific length) really won't do.

Comment: Is there any way to check valid TLD? because there is a huge list for TLD.

Comment: @rmaddy maybe just not limit the TLD length?

Comment: What about all the domains in non-English characters? A simple regex doesn't really work with today's possible domain names.

Comment: @Rox fixed for really long TLD.

Comment: One big problem still. Not all URLs require `www` at the start. Example: `http://stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: @rmaddy according to current question this is not a problem

Comment: True. The requirement in the question isn't valid.

Comment: @rmaddy but yes, I agree with you in general, will fix later

Comment: This validator requires a trailing slash on the URL (eg. it returns `false` for `http://www.facebook.com`). Unlikely to meet most people's use cases for such a function.

Answer (score 0):

In swift 2,

```
    func verifyUrl (str: String?) -> Bool {
     //Check for nil
     var urlString = str!
     if urlString.hasPrefix("http://") || urlString.hasPrefix("https://"){

     }else{
         urlString =  "http://" + urlString
     }
     let userURL:String =  urlString

     let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "((https|http)://)((\\w|-|m)+)(([.]|[/])((\\w|-)+))+", options: .CaseInsensitive)
     return regex?.firstMatchInString(userURL, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, userURL.characters.count)) != nil
   }
```